# Count Down Timer?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I make a simple application which contain a quiz questions and the user select an answer but i need your help in adding a count down timer in my app for 20 sec when this time is up it will transfer directly to the next question and when the user answer in time it will transfer to next question

Thank you

Comment: http://www.androidhub4you.com/2014/01/countdown-example-in-android-custom.html

Comment: Android has a built in class for this  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout; 
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent; 
import java.awt.event.ActionListener; 

import javax.swing.JFrame; 
import javax.swing.JLabel; 
import javax.swing.Timer; 
import javax.swing.WindowConstants; 


public class Countdown extends JFrame { 

  // Countdown 42 seconds 
  public static int counterValue = 42; 
  public static Timer timer; 
  public static JLabel label; 

  public Countdown() { 
    initGUI(); 
  } 

  private void initGUI(){ 
    BorderLayout thisLayout = new BorderLayout(); 
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); 
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(thisLayout); 
    label = new JLabel(); 
    label.setText(String.valueOf(counterValue)); 
    this.getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
    this.setTitle("Countdown Example"); 
      this.pack(); 
      this.setVisible(true); 
  } 


  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    Countdown countdown = new Countdown(); 


    Countdown.timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() { 

      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
        // =1 sec
        Countdown.counterValue--; 

        Countdown.label.setText(String.valueOf(counterValue)); 


        if(Countdown.counterValue == 0){ 
          System.out.println("Counterdown ausgelaufen!"); 

          // Timer stop
          Countdown.timer.stop(); 
        } 
      } 
    }); 

    // Timer start
    timer.start(); 
  } 
}
```

Taken from http://blog.mynotiz.de/programmieren/java-countdown-und-timer-am-beispiel-von-swing-1707/ ( German )

Answer (score 0):

The "Android way" to do timed things is by posting `Runnable` tasks to a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).